# Performance issue when reading HTML in R

Tags: r, performance, url

For a project in R, I'm scraping the HTML code from the search result-pages of a website. Say there are 100 search result pages, ranging from 'p1' to 'p100'. My code looks like this:

```
urlBase <- "http://www.somesite.com/searchresults/p"
collectURL <- list()

for(i in(1:100)){
  urlLoop <- paste(urlBase,as.character(i),sep='')
  htmlPlain <- readLines(urlLoop) # this line is taking a LOT of time
  collectURL[[i]] <- htmlParse(htmlPlain)
}
```

The readLines function takes a lot of time. I've tried other functions like getURL(), but that didn't improve the performance.

Is there some way I can speed this up in R? Or is it something else on my system or the URL / server side that's causing the slow performance?

Comment: It's really hard to help without having a reproducible case... both readLines and getURL take a lot of time but do they eventually complete the task correctly ? And what happens when you visit the same URL in a browser on the same machine ? I suspect there's something with R connecting to the internet but we need more info...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The base URL is "http://www.funda.nl/koop/heel-nederland/p". It actually has about 12,000 search result pages, which the script takes about 5 or 6 hours to complete. It does the job correctly though, the only problem is the performance.
Visiting the search result pages on my system isn't really fast, but the code is also slow on my own computer (Mac Mini 2012, not a powerhouse) and browser performance on my computer is fine.

Comment: _"You are only permitted to download one copy of the material made available on the website for personal, non-commercial use. You are not permitted without prior written consent of Funda, copy material made available otherwise, modify, distribute, disseminate, "reverse engineer", decompile or otherwise use and / or exploit."_  There's a moderate chance they're throttling you (gd for them since this is unlikely to be personal/non-commercial use).